# ip-prefix-routes with vxlan encapsulation on Juniper MX80 / MX104 17.3R3

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, vxlan, evpn

I want to check whether this configuration is acceptable by MX80 or MX104 Junos 17.3R3 (JTAC recommended version)?
Example configuration:

```
set routing-instances VPN100 instance-type vrf
set routing-instances VPN100 route-distinguisher 2.2.2.2:30100
set routing-instances VPN100 vrf-target target:123:30100
set routing-instances VPN100 vrf-table-label
set routing-instances VPN100 protocols evpn ip-prefix-routes advertise direct-nexthop
set routing-instances VPN100 protocols evpn ip-prefix-routes encapsulation vxlan
set routing-instances VPN100 protocols evpn ip-prefix-routes vni 30100
```

I cannot check this on VMX 17.3R3 because it says that vxlan encap is not supported

```
[edit routing-instances VPN100 protocols evpn]
root@VMX# show
ip-prefix-routes {
    advertise direct-nexthop;
    ##
    ## Warning: statement ignored: unsupported platform (vmx)
    ##
    encapsulation vxlan;
    ##
    ## Warning: vni must be configured with encapsulation vxlan
    ##
    vni 30100;
}
```

Maybe there is someone who can try that knobs on his router (MX80 or MX104 with junos 17.3R3) and tell me is this supported or no.
The question sounds like "whether I need to upgrade the junos to 17.3R3 on my production routers to get that functionality or that's not supported and I just need to find another solution?"

Comment: Assuming you're doing this for DCI, there are other mechanisms with EVPN to accomplish the same task that are supported in your software version.

Comment: @JordanHead it's not exactly the DCI. I want to interconnect IP VPNs from DC Network and IP VPNs from backbone MPLS network. I have another question describing my case. Please take a look if you have some thoughts about it. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70771/how-to-connect-evpn-dc-fabric-to-mpls-ip-vpn-backbone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're configuring EVPN Pure Type-5 routes (i.e. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-bess-evpn-prefix-advertisement-11#section-4.4.1) with *VXLAN transport*, this is not supported on MX80/104 until 18.2R1 (see the related [feature explorer entry](https://apps.juniper.net/feature-explorer/feature-info.html?fKey=7270&fn=EVPN%20pure%20type-5%20route%20support)).

*MPLS transport*, however, is supported as of 17.1R1.